# Add close button to custom HTML InfoBox of Bing Maps in React project

Tags: reactjs, bing-maps

There is an example of "[Custom HTML InfoBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/infoboxes/custom-html-infobox)" for Bing Maps. Ironically, there is no close button in the customized InfoBox. Every InfoBox(InfoWindow) of other map APIs (Google Map, MapBox, ) has a default close button with customized HTML content except the one of Bing Map API. It is hard to close an InfoBox without a close button.

So, I have to add a close button into the customized HTML InfoBox. The following is the pseudo code I'm writing. I'm using React + Next.js.

```js
// MyInfoBox.js
export class MyInfoBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { map, pos, events, children } = props;
    const htmlContent = renderToStaticMarkup(
      <div>
        <button onClick={events.close}>&#10006;</button>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
    const infoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.InfoBox(
      pos,
      htmlContent,
    );
    infoBox.setMap(map);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```js
// index.js
export default () => <MyInfoBox events={{ close: () => console.log('close') }} />;
```

InfoBox takes only HTML for the content parameter (why not DOM element?). Unfortunately, renderToStaticMarkup (or renderToString) renders every properties but 'onClick' to HTML. So there is no reaction when we click the close button.

How to write an available close button for custom HTML InfoBox of Bing Map in React project?

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation for several days, I find a very tricky solution. We have to register an event handler to InfoBox and detect the original source of the event. If it is the close button, invoke the corresponding callback.

```js
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.#infoWindow, 'click', e => {
      if (e.originalEvent.target.id === closeButtonId) {
        events.close(e);
      }
    });
```

It is too tricky. We'd prefer that InfoBox of Bing Maps provides the default close button (with event hooking).